# gcc preprocessor variables to string literals

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know there a bazillion question like this, but I couldn't find a good answer.
I'm compiling a source with preprocessor tokens defined in CFLAGS:

-D X=string1 -D Y=string2

I'm trying to create a string literal in my header file that combines these two values and use it in my sources like:

```
printf("%s", COMBINED);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
 #define _COMBINED(x, y) x ## y
 #define COMBINED _COMBINED(X, Y)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a string-ized token to a concatenating macro, you need a level of indirection. That means you pass it to a different macro.

```
#define COMBINED(a, b) (a##b)
#define COMBINE(a, b) COMBINED(a, b)
```

Then you pass off the params in COMBINE, in your case, X and Y

```
int main (void)  // best practice is to void-erize non-param-ed functions
{
    printf("%s\n", COMBINE(X,Y));
}
```

If you really want to do it "directly", you can do it like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_COMBINE COMBINE(X,Y)
```

And call:

```
printf("%s\n", DEFAULT_COMBINE);
```

Now, let's end with a caveat, as this is also about "best practice" so it's quite important even though it might not seem that way to you, it is, trust me on this one. Never ever, and i mean NEVER EVER start off your own preprocessor defines or constants with an underscore. Never, under any circumstances. Even if your brother works at Microsoft or worked on the Linux kernel.

In the standard and best-practice C and C++ world, the _COMBINED macro is illegal. No, not invalid, it just means you shouldn't name it like that. The short version is that constants, intrisincs and macros startign with an underscore are compiler or internal only. It's a "marker" to know that it's not something someone set.

UPDATE:

To concatenate them without being strings, you'll also need an intermediate step to stringify:

```
#define COMBINED(x1, x2)        x1##x2
#define COMBINE_STRINGS(x1, x2) COMBINED(#x1,#x2)
#define COMBINE(x1, x2)         COMBINE_STRINGS(x1, x2)
```

Comment: Hi, your suggestion kind of worked - I had to change (x##y) to (#x #y).
This is probably because the token values are not surrounded with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show an example how you call the compiler, so I made some experiments. Since commas (and other non-alphanumerical characters) will get in the way, it boiled down to the need to pass quotation marks as delimiters of the replacement text of the macros.

So I think your real issue is how to pass the strings in an equivalent way to:

```c
#define X "hello, "
#define Y "world!"
```

*Note: Here extra difficult because of comma and exclamation mark.*

If the macro replacement text is passed *including* the quotation marks, the C source gets simple. In C, you concatenate string without any intermediate operator. `"abc" "def"` is the same as `"abcdef"`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define COMBINED X Y

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", COMBINED);
}
```

Depending on your real use case, you could even simplify this to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", X Y);
}
```

In a Bash you need to escape the command line arguments like this, for example:

```bash
gcc -Wall -pedantic -D 'X="hello, "' -D 'Y="world!"' combine.c -s -O3 -o combine
```

In Windows' CMD you can escape the quotation marks like this, for example:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -D "X=\"hello, \"" -D "Y=\"world!\"" combine.c -s -O3 -o combine.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

`-D X=string1` creates a pre-processor token similar to `#define X string1`. Nothing so far makes this a string literal, you need to use the `#` "stringinizing" operator inside a function-like macro in order to do that.

Also when dealing with string literals there's no need to use token concatenation with `##` since typing two string literals after each other means they get concatenated by the preprocessor.

As usual with `#` and `##`, any macro argument that they are applied to needs to be expanded in advance before the operator is used, since these operators are always applied before token replacement. So we can't just do this:

```
#define STRCAT(x,y) #x #y
#define COMBINED STRCAT(X,Y)
// bad: result will BE "XY"
```

Instead use an additional helper macro:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define STRCAT(x,y) STR(x) STR(y)
#define COMBINED STRCAT(X,Y)
// good: result will be "string1string2"
```